# Solving $x\sqrt1+x^2\sqrt2+x^3\sqrt3+...+x^n\sqrt{n}+\dots=1$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Iterations on my calculator (up to $n=20$) give $x=0.438...$ which is very close to $x=\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{90}\right)$ although $x$ does not actually converge to it.

Can anyone provide hints as to how I can solve this problem?

Comment: The solution up to 30 digits is: $x=0.438597975797564612328218966502$ and $\sin(13\pi/90)=0.438371146789077417452734540658$

Comment: I agree that $x$ doesn't actually converge to $\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{90} \right )$ (also $\sum_{x=1}^{200}\sin^x\left(\frac{13\pi}{90} \right )\sqrt{x}=0.9989...<1)$. Could $x$ be written as a combination of functions instead of a never-ending decimal?

Comment: The series equals $\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}(x),$ where $\operatorname{Li}_s$ is the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha only gives an approximation, not a closed form:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+polylog%5B-1%2F2,x%5D+%3D+1

Comment: If you want a better approximation $\frac{3 \sqrt{9+\sqrt{19}}}{25}\approx 0.4385979307$

Comment: And, for $x=\frac{3 \sqrt{9+\sqrt{19}}}{25}$, the rhs would be $\approx 0.9999997814$

Comment: Very close. I have also discovered that $x$ is approximately $\frac{25}{57}$ although it is not as near as yours.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. If you want some rational numbers : $\frac{5168}{11783}$ makes the rhs to be $1.00000002104$, $\frac{10361}{23623}$ makes the rhs to be $1.00000000364$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n} x^n$$
is convergent in $(-1,1)$ (it can be shown that $f(x)$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) $\mathrm{Li}_{-1/2}(x)$). 
It is easy to see that $f$ is continuous, strictly increasing in $[0,1)$. Since $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=+\infty$ then by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) there is a unique $x_0\in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0)=1$. 
I would be very surprised if $x_0$ has a closed form (such as $\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{90}\right)$).

Comment: Why is it "easy to see" that $f(x)$ is negative for $x$ in $(-1,0)$?

Comment: @Did You are right, it is not straightforward.