# The radius of convergence of a formal power series.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Inspired by [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414056/solving-x-sqrt1x2-sqrt2x3-sqrt3-xn-sqrtn-1-with-x-in-mathbbr), I got curious how we can calculate the radius of convergence for the formal power series:

$$f(x) = x\sqrt1+x^2\sqrt2+x^3\sqrt3+\cdots+x^n\sqrt{n}+\cdots$$

It is easy to see that it can not be larger than $1$, but how to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ has a limit $\ell\in [0, \infty]$, the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$ is $R = \frac{1}{\ell}$. In your case $R=1$ because
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\to 1$$

Another solution here is to apply the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem).

Comment: Ah so it actually was 1. Cool!

Answer (score 3):

*Hadamard's formula*:
$$\frac1 R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n^{\tfrac1n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} n^{\tfrac1{2n}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathrm e^{\tfrac{\log n}{2n}}=\mathrm e^0.$$