# Finding the pole limiting the radius of convergence for a meromorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414076/the-radius-of-convergence-of-a-formal-power-series/2414090#2414090), once we know the radius of convergence for a formal power series...

Is there some systematic method to find out (if it is a meromorphic function), where the pole is situated that limits it's radius of convergence?

We can take the function series from the previous question as an example: $$f(x) = x\sqrt1+x^2\sqrt2+x^3\sqrt3+\cdots+x^n\sqrt{n}+\cdots$$

1. How to decide if it corresponds to a meromorphic function.
2. If that is the case, how to decide which pole is blocking our convergence.

Comment: Since the coefficients are real nonnegative, the pole closest to the origin is obviously $x=1$.

Comment: Yes, but how in general.

Comment: Are you asking for a general way to determine the points of the circle $\{z;|z|=R\}$, when $R$ is positive and finite, that are poles of a given series $f(z)$? There are none.

Comment: I suppose that is what i am asking. Is there some result showing that there can't be any or just that none have been found so far?