# Rewriting a sum of harmonic powers as a minimal polynomial

Tags: roots, minimal-polynomials

Revisiting one of my [older questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414056/solving-x-sqrt1x2-sqrt2x3-sqrt3-xn-sqrtn-dots-1-with-x-in-mathbb), I've decided to try to tackle a simpler version of the problem, this time without the square root coefficients.

> Let $x_0$ be a real number such that it satisfies the equation $$x_0+x_0^{1/2}+x_0^{1/3}+\cdots+x_0^{1/n}=1$$ for a natural number $n$. What is the minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Of course, this is possible by brute force: isolating the smallest power of $x$ then raising both sides by its reciprocal and repeating, but it becomes extremely tedious to do when $n$ is large. Also, this does not guarantee that the polynomial obtained is minimal.

This works fine for $n=1,2,3$. The minimal polynomials are, respectively, $$x-1,\quad x^2-3x+1,\quad x^5-8x^4+24x^3-21x^2+10x-1$$ and it may be interesting to note that the sign of the coefficients are alternating.

Is there an efficient way of doing this for the general case?

Comment: The "$=1$" seems arbitrary. If there is no sensible way which uses that it's the multiplicative identity (as in, say, any power of the LHS is also $=1$), then I would replece it with "$=c$", play around with that and see if there's a clearer pattern.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Fire?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, I'm still trying to work something out from the equation you wrote in your answer. I'll get back to you asap

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=y^L$, where $L$ is the least common multiple of $2,3,\dots,n$. Then you have the two equations, $y^L-x=0,y^L+y^{L/2}+y^{L/3}+\cdots+y^{L/n}-1=0$. The resultant of these two polynomials will be a polynomial satisfied by $x$. I suspect, but am not sure I could prove, that it's the minimal polynomial.

The resultant can be computed as a determinant. Unfortunately, it's the determinant of a $2L\times2L$ matrix, but at least it's a very sparse matrix. I have a hunch the problem is inherently tedious and that there's no efficient way to do it.

Comment: It looks like the first equation is trivial and the second equation is just raising each term to a power of $\text{lcm}$. However, this still avoids the method of finding a minimal polynomial.